# Print statement in Celery scheduled task doesn't appear in terminal

Tags: python, celery

When I run `celery -A tasks2.celery worker -B` I want to see "celery task" printed every second.  Currently nothing is printed.  Why isn't this working?

```
from app import app
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta

celery = Celery(app.name, broker='amqp://guest:@localhost/', backend='amqp://guest:@localhost/')
celery.conf.update(CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,)

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    print "celery task"
    return x + y

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks2.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```

This is the only output after staring the worker and beat:

```
[tasks]
  . tasks2.add

[INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You wrote the schedule, but didn't add it to the celery config.  So beat saw no scheduled tasks to send.  The example below uses `celery.config_from_object(__name__)` to pick up config values from the current module, but you can use any other config method as well.

Once you configure it properly, you will see messages from beat about sending scheduled tasks, as well as the output from those tasks as the worker receives and runs them.

```
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.config_from_object(__name__)

@celery.task
def say_hello():
    print('Hello, World!')

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-second': {
        'task': 'example.say_hello',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
    },
}
```

```
$ celery -A example.celery worker -B -l info

[tasks]
  . example.say_hello

[2015-07-15 08:23:54,350: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2015-07-15 08:23:54,366: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2015-07-15 08:23:54,377: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-07-15 08:23:55,385: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2015-07-15 08:23:55,411: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@netsec-ast-15 ready.
[2015-07-15 08:23:59,471: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task every-second (example.say_hello)
[2015-07-15 08:23:59,481: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: example.say_hello[2a9d31cb-fe11-47c8-9aa2-51690d47c007]
[2015-07-15 08:23:59,483: WARNING/Worker-3] Hello, World!
[2015-07-15 08:23:59,484: INFO/MainProcess] Task example.say_hello[2a9d31cb-fe11-47c8-9aa2-51690d47c007] succeeded in 0.0012782540870830417s: None
```

Answer (score 14):

In version 4.1.0 you have to add `logger` to your `task.py` file like so:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@task(name="multiply_two_numbers")
def mul(x, y):
    total = x * (y * random.randint(3, 100))
    #HERE:
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    return total
```

Stated halfway down in the docs here if you want more info:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html

Comment: The worker will automatically set up logging for you.

Answer (score 7):

I actually had issues printing mine on command prompt because I was using the wrong command but I found a link to a project which I forked [Project](https://github.com/codertjay/TofaProject#run-celery-for-task)

- (If on Mac ) `celery -A Project worker --loglevel=info`
- (If on Windows) `celery -A Project worker -l info --pool=solo`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run celery beat worker for scheduled tasks:

```
celery beat --app app.celery
```

Check the docs here: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler

Comment: I ran that with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but for those running into it... please check your app config. Make sure "TESTING" is set to "False". In my case it's a Flask APP, also I am updating the celery config with Flask app config

```
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

but just make sure TESTING is not set to "True",

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in [this comment](https://groups.google.com/g/celery-users/c/_ls2Svk4vK4/m/XI-3EfgluV4J) in Google Groups:

> Celerybeat doesn't execute the task, it just sends a message
> so the logging message should be produced by a worker
> not by celerybeat.

All `print` and `logging` were displayed perfectly in the console of the Celery **worker**.